# Casting a void pointer in a struct to a struct to access members

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm writing a function to remove a block of data from a dynamic array of blocks
Here I have found the specific block I want to remove, the pointer to it is startPos
And startPos is a struct of the following type.

```
typedef struct
{
    void *last; 
    int8_t pos; 
    void *data; 
    void *next; 
} DArrBlock;
```

last and next are classic linked list pointers to other DArrBlocks.
To remove the specific block, I thought the easiest way would be like this:

```
startPos->last->next = startPos->next; 
startPos->next->last = startPos->last; 
free(startPos);
```

Obviously this doesn't work since next and last are void pointers, and therefore the compiler has no way of knowing that they have the fields I'm trying to access. So you want to cast them to *DArrBlock. But how do you do this?
I thought this would be the way

```
startPos->(*DArrBlock)last->next = startPos->next; 
startPos->(*DArrBlock)next->last = startPos->last;
```

but this gives the error "base.c:106:15: error: expected identifier before '(' token"

So how do you cast a void pointer field of a structure to a pointer to a structure?

I know it can be done with an intermediate variable like this

```
prev = startPos->last; 
next = startPos->next; 
prev->next = startPos->next; 
next->last = startPos->last;
```

but I imagine that this slows things down quite a bit since you store two new pointers.

Comment: Why are you using void pointers? Make the struct not anonymous and then just do 'struct [struct name] *next' and 'struct [struct name] *last'

Comment: If you use void pointers, you would have to cast first: '((DArrBlock*)startPos->next)->last'

Comment: @lulle because then it gives me the error "Base.h:88:5: error: unknown type name 'DArrBlock'
     DArrBlock *last;"

Comment: Yes, because at that point 'DArrBlock' is not fully defined. Hence i said make the struct not anonymous, e.g. 'typedef struct DArrBlock_s'

Comment: @lulle yes that works, thank you. Guess I just dont know casting syntax after all lol

Comment: Use 'struct DArrBlock' not 'DArrBlock'

Comment: try this: `((*DArrBlock)startPos->last)->next`

Comment: @Serge yep that works, tried it when lulle mentioned it

Comment: There is some apparent confusion in the post and in some of the comments: `(*DArrBlock)` is not a cast operator, no matter what the definition of `DArrBlock` may be, because `*DArrBlock` cannot designate a type.  With a suitable definition of `DArrBlock` (not the one in the question) it would be an expression.  The wanted type is `DArrBlock *` (space optional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use void pointers in the first place, just name your struct and declare `last` and `next` as pointers to your struct:

```
typedef struct DArrBlock
{
    struct DArrBlock *last; 
    int8_t pos; 
    void *data; 
    struct DArrBlock *next; 
} DArrBlock;
```

If you use void pointers, you have to cast properly:

```
((DArrBlock*)startPos->next)->last = ...
```

As for the overhead when using a temporary variable - any decent compiler would [optimize that away](https://godbolt.org/z/Yzsd4KKG8) (when not compiling without optimizations)